# Antlr 4 Error Recovery

Tags: antlr, antlr4

My script language contains a series of macros, rule defined as following

```
program
:   macrodeclaration* EOF
;

macrodeclaration
:   (STATIC)? 'MACRO' STRING declareparameter
    statement*
    'ENDMACRO'
;
```

sometimes I mistype endmacro as endmacros, the parser gobbles up token 'endmacros' and ignore the next Macro definition, continue to search to the next endmacro.  It spits out so many no viable alternative errors.

I am wondering how do I tune the error recovery, treating mistyped endmacros as endmacro, thus just report one error and can parse the next macro correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Error recovery is a tricky subject. You could always add a new token `ENDMACROS` and allow it at the end, but then what happens if a user writes `ENDMCRO`, `endmacro`, or just `END`? Or what happens if they use `ENDMACROS` as an identifier elsewhere.

The result as it stands today is the following:

1. ANTLR 4 returns correct answers for correct input (in reality there are some known remaining bugs but the goal is always to reach this).
2. No one has implemented and submitted a better strategy for generalized error recovery as a pull request to the project which does not negatively impact performance for correct inputs.

Unless you plan on designing and implementing a generalized error recovery strategy, your best bet is probably to just add some sort of filter for errors that occur prior to the parsing stage completing. For errors that occur during semantic analysis (using visitors/walkers/etc), you can report many more errors prior to stopping.